# How to do a loop when the quantity is more than 1?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing an API to get item details from an order

The record in my database like this,

```
| order_id    | item_id | oi_qty
|MTASTO-EVHS5J|7        |2  
|MTASTO-EVHS5J|3        |1
```

my model to get this data like this

```
  public function get_order_items($order_id) {

    $this->db
            ->select('i.item_name as productTitle, oi.oi_engrave_text as notes, oi.oi_engrave_text as type')
            ->from('order_items oi')
            ->join('item i', 'oi.item_id = i.item_id', 'left')
            ->join('item_size s', 'oi.size_id = s.size_id', 'left')
            ->where('oi.order_id', $order_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query;
  }
```

in my controller doing this,

```
//order item
$nested_array = $this->inventory_api->get_order_items($order_id)->result_array();
```

make json like this,

```
//data response
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

        $default = array(
                "items"=> $nested_array
            ]

        );

        echo json_encode($default);;
```

the result in json is like this,

```
"items": [
            {
                "productTitle": "Alor",
                "notes": "costum",
                "type": "costum"
            },
            {
                "productTitle": "Rakai Maple",
                "notes": "costum",
                "type": "costum"
            }
        ]
```

In the results there are only 1 Alor items whereas in oi_qty there are 2 pieces

The question is how do I loop the item if the oi_qty is more than 1?

Comment: the code you shown will not give you the result what you show. Add code where you  fetched record and created json.

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie done, please help

Comment: In your base, you have only one entry for each product even if quantity is two. So when in your query you ask entries, it's return one by line. I think you should take the quantity in your query : `SELECT i.oi_qty as quantity ...` then parse result in a for each loop and create the number of elements you want.

Comment: @GrenierJ how can i loop while have quantity in my records?

Comment: Something like that : 

```
    foreach($items as $item)
    {
       for($i =0 ; $i < $item['quantity']; $i++)
      {
           $finalArray[] = [
             'name' => $item['name']
          ];
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your base, you have only one entry for each product even if quantity is two. So when in your query you ask entries, it returns one by line.

I think you should take the quantity in your query: `SELECT i.oi_qty as quantity ...`

Then parse the result like this

```
foreach($nested_array as $item)
{
  for($i =0 ; $i < $item['quantity']; $i++)
  {
    $finalArray[] = [
      'name' => $item['name'],,
      'note' => $item['note'],
      ...
    ];
  }
}
```